# Assign to different variable name from object

Tags: typescript

Say I have the object:

```
const obj = {
  foo: 'bar'
}
```

And I assign `foo` to a variable like so:

```
let {foo} = obj
```

Is it possible to change the variable name? I've tried using `as` like you can with Imports but that doesn't work.

```
let {foo as bar} = obj
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but my google-fu is failing me today.

Comment: `let { foo: bar } = obj;` :D Basically, LHS syntax is copied from RHS syntax, so no special stuff like `as`. [more destructuring secrets](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way, if it's just a single property, is not to use destructuring:

```
let bar = obj.foo;
```

If you want to use destructuring (perhaps you have several properties), though, give the name of the property, a colon, and the name of the variable/constant:

```
let {foo: bar} = obj;
```

Example:

```js
const obj = {
  foo: 'bar'
};
let {foo: bar} = obj;
console.log(bar);
```

Remember that object destructuring syntax *exactly mirrors* object initializer syntax. In an object initializer, `foo: bar` assigns the value from `bar` to the property `foo`:

```
const obj = {foo: bar}; // Property `foo` is assigned the value from variable `bar`
```

So in object destructuring, `foo: bar` assigns the value of the property `foo` to the variable `bar`:

```
let {foo: bar} = obj;   // Variable `bar` is assigned the value from property `foo`
```

Comment: Thats it thanks! I was assigning quite a few variables from an object so destructuring was the cleanest way to go.